# Updating Realm through a custom button on the UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, storyboard, realm

I have a tableview of "Books" that are stored in Realm. I want to set the "CurrentBook" property to "True" when hitting a button on a custom UITableViewCell.

I believe my error has something to do with getting the correct book value in "func selectCurrentBook", when I use an optional like below nothing happens.

```
@objc func selectCurrentBook(sender: UIButton) {
        try! realm.write {
            book?.currentlyReading = true
        }
    }
```

When I don't use an optional for book and use `book.currentlyReading = true` I get the error "Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value:"

Am I incorrectly passing the book value somewhere? I can't seem to find out how. Maybe I'm delegating wrong?

My TableViewCell is:

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

protocol MyBooksDelegate {
    func currentlyReadingButton()
}

class MyBooksTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    let realm = try! Realm()
    
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var authorLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var smallThumbnailImageView: UIImageView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var currentlyReadingButton: UIButton!
    
    @IBAction func currentlyReadingButton(_ sender: Any) {

    }
    
    private var book: Book!
    
    func loadImage(smallThumbnailURL: String) {
        let imageURL = URL(string: smallThumbnailURL ?? "")
        smallThumbnailImageView.sd_setImage(with: imageURL)
        }

    func configureCell(book: Book, delegate: MyBooksDelegate?) {
       titleLabel.text = book.bookTitle
       authorLabel.text = book.bookAuthor
        loadImage(smallThumbnailURL: book.bookSmallThumbnailImageURL)
        
        currentlyReadingButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(selectCurrentBook(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
                        
    }
    
    @objc func selectCurrentBook(sender: UIButton) {
        try! realm.write {
            book?.currentlyReading = true
        }
    }
}
```

My View Controller with TableView is :

```
import SwiftyJSON
import RealmSwift

class BooksViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var myBooksTableView: UITableView!
    
    let realm = try! Realm()
    
    var books: Results<Book>?
    
    // Search Bar Properties
    var searchParameter = "intitle"
    
    var booksArray: [Book] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        loadBooks()
        // Setting up the TableView
               self.myBooksTableView.delegate = self
               self.myBooksTableView.dataSource = self
               self.myBooksTableView.rowHeight = 120.0
        
        // Setup Title
        title = "My Books"
       // navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true

    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
         navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
        loadBooks()
     }
    
    func loadBooks() {
        books = realm.objects(Book.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "DateCreated", ascending: false)
        myBooksTableView.reloadData()
    }

    // TABLEVIEW
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return books?.count ?? 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyBooksTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? MyBooksTableViewCell {
            cell.configureCell(book: (books?[indexPath.row])!, delegate: self as? MyBooksDelegate)
     //       cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle.none

            return cell
        } else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "myBooksTOMyBooksDetail", sender: self)
        myBooksTableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
```

And my Book Model is:

```
class Book: Object {
    @objc dynamic var bookTitle: String!
    @objc dynamic var bookAuthor: String!
    @objc dynamic var bookSmallThumbnailImageURL: String!
    @objc dynamic var bookThumbnailImageURL: String!
    @objc dynamic var bookDescription: String!
    @objc dynamic var bookISBN_13: String!
    @objc dynamic var currentlyReading = false
    @objc dynamic var DateCreated = Date()
    @objc dynamic var WordID = UUID().uuidString
    
    // words
    let words = List<Word>()
    
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "WordID"
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you register the custom cell with the tableView? Something like `self.myTableView.register(myNib, forIdentifier: cellIdentifier)`? Also, you don't need a delegate here, you can just set the buttons target to the viewController (unless you want to handle the click elsewhere)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most compatible syntax is

```
currentlyReadingButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(selectCurrentBook), for: .touchUpInside)
```

and

```
@objc func selectCurrentBook(_ sender: UIButton) {
```

However as the cell is custom anyway I'd prefer an `IBAction` over target/action

And the protocol `MyBooksDelegate` seems to be unused.

---

Side note:

Force unwrap the cell

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyBooksTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MyBooksTableViewCell
```

A crash – with report – reveals a **design** mistake which can be fixed instantly. With the `if let` you'll see nothing and have no clue why.

---

Update:

The crash occurs because you don't set `book` in the cell, add the first line after the `{`

```
func configureCell(book: Book, delegate: MyBooksDelegate?) {
   self.book = book
   titleLabel.text = book.bookTitle
   ...
```

Comment: I Implemented your suggestion with:

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyBooksTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MyBooksTableViewCell

I'm still getting the "Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value:"

What steps should I take to resolve this?

Comment: Check the identifier and whether the class of the custom cell is set properly in Interface Builder.

Comment: Identifier is "MyBooksTableViewCell" and class is also "MyBooksTableViewCell". I kept checking that because I thought that would be the problem too.

Comment: Check it again. The identifier is in Attributes Inspector, it's not the Restoration ID.

Comment: Yeah thats always the first thing I check along with making sure the DataSource and Delegate are set correctly.

Comment: Added screenshots to the question for proof

Comment: Set the Exception Breakpoint to get the exact location of the crash and the variable values. Most likely an outlet in the cell is not connected.

Comment: I posted the exact error line above. 

When I put the breakpoint I get the error "Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1"

I've tripled checked for any outlet on the cells not connected

Comment: That Works! Thank you!